What is meant by "per user" write requests in the Google People API?
If I integrate the Google People API into my Chrome extension, do the "per user" write requests refer to each individual user of the extension or to my Google Cloud Console account?
For example, does "30 write requests per minute per user" mean that each individual user of my Chrome extension has 30 write requests per minute, or does it mean that the extension can only send a total of 30 write requests to the API per minute?
Thank you for your help :)
Before I proceed with the API integration, I would like to clarify this question.

That is usually tied to whose access token you are using. Is every user logging in to Google via your extension, so that you are using their own user access token to make API requests? Or are you using some sort of client/application token?

The 30 write requests per minute limit applies to the project itself, not the individual user who enables the API. This means that any user who makes write requests through the API within that project will be subject to the same limit, regardless of their own individual API quota.
If you enable the People API in an extension that other users will use, all write requests made through that extension will count towards the project's limit, not your personal limit. This is because the API calls are executed using the project's credentials, not your individual user credentials.
More about the Google People API quotas:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/people.googleapis.com/quotas
You can always ask for more quota by:

Go into the quota tab
Click the pencil icon next to one of the quotas
Click the link apply for higher quota
Submit the form

Or create a Google support ticket to request more quota if the business needs are more than the quota that is accepted after sending the form previously mentioned.
